# Duplicate column in select query gives faster query execution

Tags: mysql, database-performance

Getting some strange behavior from MySQL 5.6. The following query is supposed to select some simple data from a join. Which works fine.

```
SELECT 
  f.followID, 
  l.object_id,
  l.created_at,
  ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(l.created_at)/(3600)) window
FROM fb_follow f LEFT JOIN fb_likes l ON f.followID = l.user_id
WHERE f.profileID = 1
  AND l.created_at > '20171119' LIMIT 1000;
```

The strange thing happen when I mistakenly included a duplicate of the `l.created_at` line.

```
SELECT 
  f.followID, 
  l.object_id,
  l.created_at,
  l.created_at,
  ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(l.created_at)/(3600)) window
FROM fb_follow f LEFT JOIN fb_likes l ON f.followID = l.user_id
WHERE f.profileID = 1
  AND l.created_at > '20171119' LIMIT 1000;
```

The query execution time went from ~600ms to ~350ms (repeated for different values of `f.profileID`. What can be the reason for lower query time? My expectation is that it would at least take less time since less data to return?

Comment: Was this run immediately after the first? The reason is if the data in question was still in memory, it might've run faster for that alone. Or did you see this in repeat (cycled) runs between both?

Comment: Yes repeated runs on both examples with the same result.

Comment: Cache like in InnoDB bufferpool (memory) and Hard disk cache are likly to cause lower execution time

Comment: Also tried with `SQL_NO_CACHE` in the query.

Comment: Run this command before running select query. FLUSH QUERY CACHE; RESET QUERY CACHE;  If time is same for both then post the output of Explain statement for both.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the permissions to do that. But I have repeatedly run query1, query2, query1, ... with same results. Can it still be cache?

Comment: Cache could hold the table (not the result) and hence your attempt query1, query2,... would not cause the cache to be flushed.

Comment: But wouldn't cache hold both queries?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my logic (that could be wrong of course) is that cache makes sense in relation to SOURCE of information as opposed to results of query, and this under the assumption that the DB estimates that there are low chances that the very same query will be issued several times one after the other, while the same SOURCE could be consulted with some repetition.

Answer (score 1):

**Two caches**

Changing `SELECT` to `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE` eliminates the use of the "Query cache".

Usually when the query cache is used, the query time is 1ms or less.  350ms says that it was not the QC.

The other main cache is InnoDB's buffer_pool.  (You *are* using InnoDB, correct?)  When you first run a query, it *may* need to hit the disk to get the index and/or data blocks.  The second time, those blocks *may* still be cached in the buffer_pool (which is in RAM), hence the query will be faster.

The difference is often a factor of 10.  But there are many exceptions.  600 vs 350 does not fit the pattern, but that is inconclusive.

So, when timing do two things:

1. SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...
2. Run the query twice, and use the second timing.

**EXPLAIN**

Please run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each variation.  If there is any difference (which I doubt), that may give new insight into why "duplicating a line changed the timing".

**JOIN**

Don't use `LEFT` when you don't need it.  It confuses the reader.  Since you are explicitly filtering on `f.profileID = 1`, the `LEFT` is ignored (and can be removed).

**ORDER BY**

Having a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is usually folly.  Which 1000 rows do you want?  Adding an `ORDER BY` would make the decision explicit.  Yes, it may slow down the query.

**Useful INDEXes**

For better performance:

```
`f` needs INDEX(followID, profileID)   -- in this order
`u` needs INDEX(created_at)
```

Comment: (EXPLAIN) Both returns the same explanation.

(INDEXING) I realize now that there are index missing in the database that I thought were in place. Regarding `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` the use case is more of a sample so the order is not that important (but good point).

Comment: Yes, "sampling" is a valid reason for skipping the `ORDER BY`.  (However, most questions on this forum are about production queries; so I jumped to a wrong conclusion.)